# Boundary on some layers in snapshot

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I have shapefiles and a tiff image that I am taking a snapshot of from a command prompt. The tiff layer always has a 3 pixel boundary. You can see the buildings and contours continue across the gap. What causes this and how can I keep if from happening?

[image]